# Colors common to multiple parts?

Tags: piece-information, colour, bricklink

New AFOL here, learning the ropes of BrickLink searches.

Can't see how to do this, yet:

For which specific colors are all of the following parts available?

- 2 x 2 Brick *(Part# 3003)*.

  [image]
- 1 x 2   Plate *(Part# 3023)*.

  [image]
- 2 x 2 Tile *(Part# 3068. Either 3068a or 3068b)*.

  [image]
- 2 x 2 Inverted Tile (*Part# 11203*).

  [image]

For bonus points (10000 thanks, give or take), is there a simple way to find these specific colors using the query capabilities in BrickLink?

Comment: In my experience from buying pieces ether through BL, LEGO.com, eBay, or the local shop in town, is to take note on the "condition" of the pieces.  These more common colors fade or look dirty over time: White, Yellow, Blue, Light Gray.  It was just easier for me to always buy them "New" vs. "Used".  Tiles get scratched up easily too. Since they tend to be the first thing you see on a build, I would avoid buying them "used" no matter the color.  So, basically, keep an eye out on mixed conditions, which can ruin the desired effect of a project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to figure out what colors a set of parts have in common is to use BrickLink’s Stud.io digital design software. I am unable to show screenshots at the moment, but here are the steps:

1. Open Stud.io
2. Place the parts in question on your virtual building workspace (doesnt matter in which color)
3. Select all the parts together, either by:

   - using the mouse to draw a selection square around the parts
   - using the mouse and the CTRL key to select parts one by one
   - using the parts list on the right side of the screen (the Step list) and with CTRL pressed selecting the parts there
4. In the Top of the right sidebar under “Color Palette”, click on the dropdown with the color name in it. This dropdown will show only the colors that the selected parts have in common.

You will have to check the “Hide unavailable colors” checkbox in this dropdown to make it work.

Comment: And to you Phil: 8.33626! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you need to check available color for each individual part:

[3003](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=272#T=C)
[3023](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=378#T=C)
[3068](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=17085#T=C)
[11203](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=110717#T=C)

From what I can see most of the colors 11203 comes in are available in other parts as well.

Following your edit I can suggest another option for you - [Color Guide](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogColors.asp?utm_content=subnav). Select a color and click on Parts column to find all parts available in particular color.

Comment: Thanks Alex - 8.33626! thanks to you.